# Cannot display Greek characters .mdb file (PHP & ODBC)

Tags: php, ms-access, character-encoding, odbc

I am having problems displaying text from a column in an MS Access 2007 table which is in Greek. I am using PHP and `$dbc = @odbc_pconnect("Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)};Dbq=$mdbFilename", $user, $pass);` to read from a local .mdb file. I can successfully read the rest of the data in the DB which is in Latin characters. Greek characters get displayed as `�` when I echo the results. The html charset is properly set to utf-8. I've tried using utf8_encode with no luck. I've been searching the web for some time no but could not figure it out.

Any help would be appreciated.

Kyris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.mdb` format, being a Microsoft's invention does not use Unicode, but rather one of `Windows-` codepages. Check which one is that you use for Greek, and use [iconv](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.iconv.php) to translate between encodings.

Comment: thanks man. I've actually used iconv to convert from Windows-1252 because I thought that was the default for .mdb files but I didn't think to look for a different codepage for Greek characters. For the record, for Greek it's Windows-1253 and iconv() did the job. Thanks again!

Comment: Awesome! I spent some time on figuring it once :)

Comment: Hey mate. I've got another related problem. While the results were properly displayed on my local machine (using XAMPP), when I uploaded the website on a Windows hosting plan with GoDaddy, the characters were again not shown correctly. Apparently iconv() does convert them to UTF-8 (because if I don't use the function they are shown differently) but this time question marks are displayed (without the black background color). What could be the problem? Perhaps something with my hosting plan?

Comment: Do you have touble with unicode characters coming from other sources too, or only those from database?

Comment: nope! only for the values from the database. the rest of the page is mainly in greek, anyway..

Comment: I'm not sure really. I think you can safely start another question with all the additional information.

Answer (score 1):

As an exmple:

```
echo 'TRANSLIT : ', iconv("Windows-1253", "UTF-8//TRANSLIT", $text);
echo 'IGNORE   : ', iconv("Windows-1253", "UTF-8//IGNORE", $text);
echo 'Plain    : ', iconv("Windows-1253", "UTF-8", $text);
```