# Greek characters from .mdb file shown on local machine but not on web server

Tags: php, encoding, character-encoding, iconv

I've used the PHP function iconv() to convert greek text from an .mdb file from Windows-1253 to UTF-8 in order to display them on a website instead of having question marks. At first I succeeded while testing my script using XAMPP on my local machine and the greek text was shown properly in the browser. I also asked a question on how to do it here:

[Cannot display Greek characters .mdb file (PHP & ODBC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135499/cannot-display-greek-characters-mdb-file-php-odbc)

However, when I uploaded the website on my Godaddy's Windows server, the question marks reappeared. I tried removing the iconv() function to see if the results were different, and they were indeed different (different sort of encoding apparently but still question marks instead of proper greek characters). So, as far as I understand, the function iconv() works but the characters are not shown in the page. I tried using other browsers with no luck. The html charset is set to utf-8 in the headers. Could it be a problem with the hosting plan? The rest of the text in the page (mostly Greek) is shown properly apart from the text that is extracted from the database.

Any help would be appreciated,

Kyris

edit: php test code

`<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">`

`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

`<head>`

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />`

`<title>Test Page</title>`

`</head>`

`<body>`

`<?php`

`require('access.php');`

`$temptype = 'Gardener';`

`$q = "SELECT TOP 1 ExpenseAccountGreek FROM ExpenseAccount WHERE ExpenseAccount = '$temptype'";`

`$r = @odbc_exec($dbc,$q);`

`$greektype[0] = @odbc_fetch_array($r);`

`$paymentsT[0]['Type'] = iconv('Windows-1253','UTF-8',$greektype[0]['ExpenseAccountGreek']);`

`echo $paymentsT[0]['Type'];`

`@odbc_close($dbc);`

`?>`

`</body>`

`</html>`

Answer (score 0):

It may well depend on host, since if the server specifies a charset in HTTP headers, it overrides anything that you can say in your document. Check out the headers using e.g.
http://www.rexswain.com/httpview.html

Comment: the Receiving Header is:

HTTP/1.1·200·OK(CR)(LF)
Cache-Control:·no-store,·no-cache,·must-revalidate,·post-check=0,·pre-check=0(CR)(LF)
Pragma:·no-cache(CR)(LF)
Content-Length:·0(CR)(LF)
Content-Type:·text/html(CR)(LF)
Expires:·Thu,·19·Nov·1981·08:52:00·GMT(CR)(LF)
Server:·Microsoft-IIS/7.0(CR)(LF)
Set-Cookie:·PHPSESSID=eiheu7amalimiil5dfmbmel2o7;·path=/(CR)(LF)
X-Powered-By:·ASP.NET(CR)(LF)
Date:·Tue,·07·Feb·2012·09:40:23·GMT(CR)(LF)
Connection:·close(CR)(LF)
(CR)(LF)

no character set displayed here although I do specify it in the header of my pages..

Comment: What is the actual data sent by the server? There are various potential explanations (different versions of PHP, differences in database access, issues when uploading files from local system to server), but it is usually best to analyze exactly what the server sends, at byte level, for the problem characters.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So how should I show you what the server sends? What do I have to do? The PHP script sends a query to the .mdb file located in a folder on the web server and receives some data in greek. That data is then displayed in a table. (Note that when I was testing it locally, the .mdb file being read was located on my computer while when testing it online it was reading it from the same uploaded version of the .mdb file located on the web server.)

Comment: A URL might help. It depends on what input data is needed.

Comment: well I've put some sample code into a test page where PHP retrieves a single value from the database and tries to display it as I was doing in the complete page. On my machine this word is shown properly in greek, on the web server it's displayed with question marks: http://www.fox-propertymanagement.com/test2.php . I don't know if this helps..

Comment: This helps to identify that the server actually sends question mark characters, as opposite to other data that browsers might fail to render properly, using question mark like symbols instead. An oddity is that one character, the third one, is a Latin letter. If you can post some relevant part of the PHP code and identify e.g. the Greek data that somehow gets sent as “??p?????”, maybe someone could make a guess..

Comment: Ok the reason i am executing this query is to get the greek corresponding string which is matched to an english one. In this example, I chose the string "Gardener" which matches in the DB to the greek "Κηπουρός". Obviously the 3rd letter is the greek letter pi (π) which is often used in maths and this might be the reason that it gets displayed properly. I will edit the original post in order to display the php code that I used for this test page.

Comment: any ideas? I tried inserting a php5.ini in the root of my server with the default charset set to utf-8 and now phpinfo() ( www.fox-propertymanagement.com/phpinfo.php ) shows that the charset is indeed set to utf-8 (before it was set to no value). But still, the greek characters are not displayed as they should have been..