# PHP query / mdb encoding issue question mark using odbc query

Tags: php, sql, ms-access, odbc

I have a problem getting some data from a mdb database. I have a table persons with name and surname in Spanish so i have tildes like 'Agustí' and 'ñ'. Making the query it shows like this:

Alexis Agust� Sans

I don´t have much idea about encoding but i think the solution is encoding to utf-8. I am right?.

I add here the code of the query, it´s very simple:

```
 // Connection is Ok, don´t worry for it
 $cidl=odbc_connect($dsnl, $usuariol, $clavel, SQL_CUR_USE_ODBC);
 $queryl = "SELECT * from personas where val=1";
 $resultl = odbc_exec($cidl, $queryl);
 while(odbc_fetch_row($resultl))
 {
 $nombre=odbc_result($resultl, 'nombre');
 $apellidos=odbc_result($resultl, 'apellido');
 $nombreCompleto=$nombre.' '.$apellidos;
 echo $nombreCompleto;
 }
```

How can i get the surname('apellido') without question mark?

Thanks.

Comment: Mikel, I think your answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9135499/cannot-display-greek-characters-mdb-file-php-odbc?rq=1

Comment: Did you try [mb-detect-encoding](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mb-detect-encoding.php) and some other useful functions to get encoding you have and convert it to a right one?